# Changing launcher activity after receiving data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

```
binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkValid()
            if (valid){

                Intent(this, DailyActivity::class.java).also{
                    it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMI", calculateBmi().round(1))
                    it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMR", calculateBmr().round(2))
                    startActivity(it)
                }
            }
        }
```

The MainActivity of my app takes some data from the user to calculate his/her BMI and BMR and uses that data in the main portion of the app which is in another activity called DailyActivity. I want to make it so that the first time a user launches the app, it asks for the data. But after the first time, every time the user launches the app it should directly launch DailyActivity with the previously entered data. (Pressing the back button shouldn't show MainActivity either). How can I implement this?

Comment: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: I get that I can save and retrieve that data with SharedPreferences, but how do I make it so that the DailyActivity becomes the launcher activity every time the user launches the app after entering the data?

Comment: You can have a LauncherActivity just to read SharedPreferences and then choose wich activity to start, you can disable transitions, animations, etc in LauncherActivity so the user won't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, change this Activity with your own code

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var sharedPreference: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            checkValid()
            if (valid){


                //save data to preferences
                val editor = sharedPreference.edit()
                editor.putBoolean("IS_NOT_FIRST_TIME", true)
                editor.putFloat("EXTRA_BMI",calculateBmi().round(1))
                editor.putFloat("EXTRA_BMR",calculateBmr().round(2))
                editor.apply()
                
                Intent(this, DailyActivity::class.java).also{
                    it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMI", calculateBmi().round(1))
                    it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMR", calculateBmr().round(2))
                    startActivity(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        sharedPreference =  getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        
        // cek preference for previously entered data
        if (sharedPreference.getBoolean("IS_NOT_FIRST_TIME", false )){
            Intent(this, DailyActivity::class.java).also{
                it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMI", sharedPreference.getFloat("EXTRA_BMI", 0.0f))
                it.putExtra("EXTRA_BMR", sharedPreference.getFloat("EXTRA_BMI", 0.0f))
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each time activity open, it will check if data was entered. If not first time, it will execute auto intent to DailyActivity with data from preferences

Comment: `DailyActivity` can read the share preferences, therefore, we don't need to pass data from `MainActivity2`